# Drag and drop image from Windows Explorer to Outlook email (2013) as inline image

Tags: images, drag-and-drop, microsoft-outlook-2013

I would swear that was possible in earlier versions of Outlook:

1. Open New Email in Outlook
2. Ensure HTML Format
3. Drag .png file from Windows Explorer into the email

I *wish* the email is now part of the message but in fact the picture is an attachment.

Is it possible to drop images into an HTML message?

Comment: Does it only act this way with PNG's, or do JPG's act the same way?  What bit-depth is the PNG (PNG24, or PNG32 kind of thing)?  Do you have Word set as your editor in Outlook?

Comment: gif, jpeg, all the same, land as attachments.

Comment: If you use "Insert-->Picture" does it insert it in-line?

Comment: yes, insert picture works as expected.

Comment: You're only trying to drag'n'drop 1 image at a time correct?

Comment: yes, 1 image, totally basic. and it strictly goes into the mail as attachment even when I drop it inside the text.

Comment: The only work around I can come up with is an add-on that you could drop the image onto and it inserts at cursor position. That's a little too time consuming for me to throw together though.

Answer (score 3):

Add "Copy as image" to the Explorer context menu.  Paste in Outlook.

**Part 1: nircmd**

Use the utility [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to copy the file to the clipboard as an image.  Then, paste the image into Outlook.

```
nircmd.exe clipboard copyimage <filename>
```

**Part 2: Add to context-menu**

For efficiency, consider adding this as a context (right-click) menu item.

1. Download and extract `nircmd` to `C:\utils`
2. Create the registry key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy as image\command`
3. Set the `(default)` value of the key to `C:\utils\nircmdc.exe clipboard copyimage "%1"`

This add "Copy as image" to the context menu for all files (not just images).  If the file is not an image, the command does not copy anything.

For this solution to work only for specific file types, perform the steps above and replace the asterisk in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\` with the file type in a special key (example: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.png\`).

Comment: This is excellent but the context menu item doesn't show up when I put it under specific extensions. e.g. [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg\shell\Copy as image\command]

Comment: Oops!  I had the path wrong.  It should be `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.png`.  See edit.

Comment: I'd also suggest extracting to C:\windows (or someplace already on path) because C:\utils isn't standard and adds a "go edit your path environment variable" step. ..Although if one is venturing into fixes like this, it's best to have a separate folder for things added to path.

Comment: You don't need it in your PATH variable if you specify the full path: `C:\...\whatever.exe`